# password_verify not working with hash_string from database

Tags: php

when I'm retrieving a bcrypt hash from MySQL, using PDO

```
$password_hash = $result_set_database['hash_value'];
```

and use it to verify

```
if(password_verify($password, $password_hash))
  { echo "valid";}
else
  {echo "invalid";}
```

i'm always getting invalid as the response, but i've tried manually coding the hash like this,

```
$password_hash = '$2y$12$rSMqbIqhOga5Qnbv9dCfoeE4HRqJKyJqSRk8c8bUl9w.cVkXVfsdW'// string is "password"
```

and now this works with password_verify, but wont for the same hash value stored in the database,

My database password hash column has a size of 255 varchar

Why is this happening?

Comment: How do you retrieve the hash from DB? can you paste that code snippet too?

Comment: And you should generate the password hash using `password_hash` to use `password_verify()` function

Comment: `this works with password_verify, but wont for the same hash value stored in the database` - which means when you pull it out of the database, you're not using what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a quick test:

```
$password = 'password';
$hash     = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$dbHash   = '$2y$12$rSMqbIqhOga5Qnbv9dCfoeE4HRqJKyJqSRk8c8bUl9w.cVkXVfsdW';

$result   = password_verify($password, $hash);
$dbResult = password_verify($password, $dbHash);

var_dump($result);
var_dump($dbResult);
```

In both cases we get `true`:

```
boolean true
boolean true
```

Comment: `strlen($password_hash)` gave 61 instead of 60 PDO added a whitespace to the end of my hash!

Comment: It's very werid thing. Mayby column has set length to `61` ? Or during the fetching you add a whitespace somehow ? Dummy solution can be using `trim` method.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen($password_hash)` gave 61, a whitespace added to hash, i'm suspecting something to do with `PDO` , using `trim($password_hash)` before checking solved the issue

Comment: `a whitespace added by PDO` - maybe it's not what you mean but that statement is not going to be true. PDO only does what you tell it, it's not going to manipulate your database data by randomly appending spaces to things.